# Run selenium grid hub and node the same machine

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I am trying to run selenium grid,

details: win 7, selenium 2.4.5, selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0, java 8, and i get an error :

*Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'STUDENT-1-DT', ip: '192.168.168.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)*

My code is:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    RemoteWebDriver remoteWD = null;
    try {
        remoteWD = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://http://192.168.81.101:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    remoteWD.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement element = remoteWD.findElement(By.name("q"));
    element.sendKeys("Packt Publishing");
    remoteWD.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I change:

```
RemoteWebDriver remoteWD =new RemoteWebDriver(newURL("http://http://192.168.81.101:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

to:

```
WebDriver remoteWD= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```